# Background-image won't appear in HTML

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put an image within the header but its not showing up.

I've tried looking for spelling errors, missing ending semi colons, tried it in different browsers, and made sure the picture is in the same folder as the rest of the HTML and CSS files... Not sure what else to do. This is how I coded the header in CSS.

```
header { background-color: #9BC1C2;
   background-image: lilyheader.jpg;
   background-position: right;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 150px; }
```

I want the header to appear on each page of the website and it should have the title on it too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a pair of parentheses like this:

```
background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
```

The correct way of doing this would be

```
header {
    background-color: #9BC1C2;
    background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just as the guys above have mention make sure you specify the correct path within a strings if that doesn't work then must definitely be your permission go to your terminal and chmod 404 or 605 to file of your choice.

example:

```
cd public_html
chmod 404 logo.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check your jpg path, use relative path or absolute path.

Comment: Relative or absolute path? I'm new to this, i apologize.

Comment: is your html, css and image are all in the same directory?

Comment: theyre all in the same folder, yes

Comment: Hi @niucang, welcome to StackOverflow. I am writing to let you know that this kind of answer is not very helpful on its own. Please be as specific as possible to avoid confusion.

Comment: @HughGuiney . ah oh, sorry for that. but I think this is the shortest answer to the question.